# Mongodb FindOne returns object with undefined property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, postman

I'm trying to get a user from my collection with findOne using its name attribute but it returns undefined whereas my user is in the db.

This is my schema :

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter a name"],
    maxlength: 32,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: [6, "Password must be at least 6 characters"],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});

const Userdb = mongoose.model("userdb", schema);

module.exports = Userdb;
```

And this is where i try to get my user :

```
const name = req.body.name;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const user = Userdb.findOne({name: name});
  // console.log(user.name, user.password);
  if (user.name === undefined)
    return res.status(400).send({ message: "User not found" });

  const dbpassword = user.password;
```

where my console.log returns undefined

In the db :

[image: screenshot]

My postman post request :

[image: screenshot postman]

Comment: Did you get the value for `name` in Node.JS. If not, in Postman, select raw (radio button), next choose JSON, and with value `{ "name": "rio", "password": "rio" }`.

Comment: `const user = Userdb.findOne({name: name});` should be `const user = await Userdb.findOne({name: name});`. It's an asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your body request and sure you has data in db collection with this condition. If data of collection has not match query mongoose return you undifined.

- Send request in raw mode and set Json type to send request

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qRpp.png)

And you should create async function and use await for get data then log that

```
const user = await Userdb.findOne({name: name});
```